# Exact sequence of $A$-modules

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

I was trying to demonstrate the Proposition 2.9 of Atiyah and MacDonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*. But I couldn't do the following:

> Let $M$, $M'$, and $M''$ be $A$-modules, $v$ and $u$ be homomorphisms, and
>   $$0 \longrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}(M'',N) \stackrel{\bar{v}}\longrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}(M,N) \stackrel{\bar{u}}\longrightarrow\operatorname{Hom}(M',N)$$
>   be a sequence exact for all $A$-module $N$. Then the sequence
>   $$M' \stackrel{u}\longrightarrow M \stackrel{v}\longrightarrow M'' \longrightarrow 0$$
>   is exact. Here, $\bar{v}(f)=f\circ v$ and $\bar{u}(g)=g\circ u$.

I suppose there is a particular A-module N that holds this, but I couldn't find it.

Somebody can help me? Thanks.

Comment: This is also proved in detail in Dummit & Foote.

Comment: I don't agree with the close vote. There it is only asked why $v$ is surjective.

Comment: This is because the rest is proved in the book.

Answer (score 6):

You will find several solutions in the comments and in some books, but actually the statement is, from a "higher" perspective, almost the definition of an exact sequence. Let me explain this.

By definition, $M' \xrightarrow{u} M \xrightarrow{v} M'' \to 0$ is exact iff $v$ is surjective and $\mathrm{im}(u)=\mathrm{ker}(v)$. This means equivalently that $v$ induces an isomorphism $\mathrm{coker}(u)=M/\mathrm{im}(u) \cong M''$. Now, [cokernels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cokernel) have a universal property, and it is a general fact that objects are determined by their universal property (Yoneda Lemma). Hence, $M' \xrightarrow{u} M \xrightarrow{v} M'' \to 0$ is exact iff $v$ is **a** cokernel of $u$ which means that $vu=0$ and for all morphisms $M \to T$ which vanish when composed with $u$ there is a unique factorization over $v$. But this exactly means that $0 \to \hom(M'',T) \to \hom(M',T) \to \hom(M,T)$ is exact for all $T$.

Similarly, a sequence $0 \to M'' \to M'  \to M$ is exact iff $M'' \to M'$ is **a** kernel of $M' \to M$ iff $0 \to \hom(T,M'') \to \hom(T,M') \to \hom(T,M)$ is exact for all $T$.

(When you want to prove this directly, you will just repeat the proof of the Yoneda Lemma in a special case; this happens all the time because category theoretic principles are almost ignored in teaching...)

Comment: Isn’t it $0 \rightarrow Hom(M’’, T) \rightarrow Hom(M, T) \rightarrow Hom(M’, T)$ at the second paragraph? Anyway, it really helped me a lot to have an intuition what’s going on here.