# A statement on exact sequences of R-modules.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

My question is related to the answer of this post:
[Exact sequence of $A$-modules](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1001384/exact-sequence-of-a-modules?noredirect=1&lq=1).
I am trying to understand this answer, but I am stuck at the following statement.

Given is a sequence $A\stackrel {f}{\longrightarrow } B\stackrel {g}{\longrightarrow } C\longrightarrow 0$ of left R-modules. Given is that $g$ "induces" (what does this mean in this context?) an isomorpism $\mbox{coker } (f) = B/\mbox{im } (f)\cong C$. Prove that $A\stackrel {f}{\longrightarrow } B\stackrel {g}{\longrightarrow } C\longrightarrow 0$ is exact, i.e., $g$ is surjective and $\mbox{im } (f) = \ker (g)$. Can anybody help me to prove this? Because I do not see it.

Is there a dual statement?

Comment: An algebraist may shout me down here but I believe the term 'induced' arises from the first isomorphism theorem. In that, if $g$ is surjective then $B$ is isomorphic to $B / \ker g$ for which the result follows since the above sequence is exact, hence $\ker g = \text{Im} f$.

Comment: Why is $C$  isomorphic to $B/ \ker g$ ?

Comment: A typo in my first comment, I meant to write $C$ is isomorphic to $B / \ker g$. In answer to you recent comment, it is by the first isomorphism theorem, check the wiki link for some details https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorem#First_isomorphism_theorem

Comment: The first isomorphism theorem states that $B/ \ker g\cong \mbox{im } g$. Note that it is not given that the sequence is exact, it has to be proven that the sequence is exact.

Answer (score 7):

If $h:P\to Q$ is a homomorphism of some sort (of groups, modules, rings, etc.), then the statement that $h$ induces a homomorphism $\widetilde{h}:P/S\to Q$ for a given subobject $S$ of $P$ (subgroup, submodule, ideal, etc.) implicitly says that $S\subseteq\ker(h)$, and that $\widetilde{h}$ is defined on cosets by $\widetilde{h}(p+S)=h(p)$ for any $p\in P$.

The key facts are that

- $\widetilde{h}$ is injective $\iff$ $S=\ker(h)$, and
- $\widetilde{h}$ is surjective $\iff$ $h$ is surjective

so if we're told that $h$ induces an isomorphism $P/S\cong Q$, then we know that $S=\ker(h)$ and that $h$ is surjective (or in other words that $Q=\mathrm{im}(h)$).

Thus, if you're given a sequence of maps of left $R$-modules $$A\xrightarrow{\;\;f\;\;}B\xrightarrow{\;\;g\;\;}C\longrightarrow 0$$
and told that $g$ induces an isomorphism $B/\mathrm{im}(f)\cong C$, then by the two facts above, you can conclude that $\mathrm{im}(f)=\ker(g)$ and that $C=\mathrm{im}(g)$ (i.e., that $g$ is surjective).

Answer (score 2):

"g "induces"" means that the map $$\begin{matrix}B/Im(f)&\longrightarrow&C\\\overline{x}&\longmapsto&g(x)\end{matrix}$$ is an isomorphism.

Now, given $y\in Im(f)$ then $\overline{y}=\overline{0}$, so $\overline{y}\longmapsto 0=g(y)$. Therefore $Im(f)\subseteq Ker(g)$. For other hand, if $x\in Ker(g)$, then $g(x)=0\in C$. Thus, $\overline{x}$ belongs to kernel of the isomorphism. Hence $x\in Im(f)$ and so $Ker(g)\subseteq Im(f)$.

Since $Im(f)=Ker(g)$, then the sequence is exact in $B$ and $B/Ker(g)=B/Im(f)$ is isomorphic to $C$ and $Im(g)$. Therefore $C=Im(g)$. It follows that the sequence is exact.